# Не понимаю как написать код

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал изучать циклы но вообще не понимаю как сделать это в коде.

Comment: Начнем с простого: вы знаете как в цикле посчитать сумму чисел от 1 до 30?

Comment: Нет, вот это я не очень понимаю

Comment: Это вообще самая база. Посмотрите эту статью: https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/summa-i-proizvedenie-posledovatelnosti-chisel

Comment: Ну теперь знаю а что дальше?

Comment: Если знаете - значит можете решить задачу из вопроса.

Comment: Текст задачи неполный. Не хватает "Ответ напишите в виде натуральной дроби" 

Comment: @Эникейщик, 218572480850557 / 2329089562800 ( `sum(Fraction(i, (31-i)) for i in range(1, 31))` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой "новичковский" алгоритм:

```
s = 0

for i in range(1, 31):
    s += i / (31 - i)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(sum([ i / (31-i) for i in range(1, 31) ]))
```